# Replace between brackets content sublime & regex

Tags: linux, regex, grep, sublime-text-3

I've actually got lines like this:

```
[Sat Dec 31 18:24:18.700 2022] 0.017 sec 0.017 sec [all/2/rel 37 (0,700) @groupparentid] [post]keyword
```

How can I delete the whole line starting with bracket `[` and ending bracket `]` to keep only `keyword`?

I'm actually using sublime text editor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Perhaps this is due to use of a translation tool? Could you try rephrasing the question to make it more clear. Also, this is pretty simple as it is described. Is the issue possibly more complex or better described given more samples?

Answer (score 0):

To keep only `keyword` after replacement use this regex with empty replacement:

```
\[.*\]
```

It will match everything between first opening square bracket and last closing square bracket.

If you want to remove paired square brackets without nesting (similarly to your own answer), you could use simple `\[.*?\]` (or `\[.*?\]\s*` to remove also spaces after closing bracket)

This regex will match everything between opening square bracket and nearest following closing square bracket. In case of provided example this will be result (if replace with empty string):

```
0.017 sec 0.017 sec keyword
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this should do the job !

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Explaining HOW it does the job will help make this an answer. Right now it is just a comment. I understand you've solved this problem yourself, but note that the questions here and their answers must be helpful to others coming later with the same question. Use the EDIT button to make this a better answer.